# Is the bee mount actually obtainable in BfA?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I know you can ride one when you use the [flight master](https://www.wowhead.com/npc=142060/colony-caretaker) near the bee hive in Stormsong Valley, but that's just a taxi and no obtainable mount.

Is there a real bee mount in BfA we can actually obtain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bee Mount as of game version 8.0.1 is only partially implemented: while there is a model, the spell that summons it is still explicitly marked as a placeholder spell (https://www.wowhead.com/spell=259741/ph-bee-mount#comments) and summons an entirely different mount. There is also not yet an entry in the mount journal, nor is there an item that teaches the spell. There isn't even yet an official name for the mount. The mount will probably be released at one point, but at this point it cannot yet be obtained. I will try to update this answer when more is known about the mount.

Answer (score 0):

The Bee has been confirmed as a mount coming with patch 8.2 at the Blizzcon. This patch also introduces flying on the BfA continents.

Screenshot of the Blizzcon presentation:

[image]